# Go AWS S3 SDK: Optimal way to fetch buckets which have a certain key/value tag

Tags: go, amazon-s3

I have a function which pulls all AWS S3 buckets that are tagged with a specific key and value.
This method is not optimal. It loops through all buckets and calls
s3svc.GetBucketTagging for each. So the time complexity is N+1. Do you guys know a better approach?

```
func (p *awsS3Provisioner) GetBucketsTaggedWith(tag *s3.Tag) ([]*s3.Bucket, error) {

    result, err := p.s3svc.ListBuckets(&s3.ListBucketsInput{})
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    matchedBuckets := []*s3.Bucket{}
    if result != nil && result.Buckets != nil && len(result.Buckets) > 1 {
        for _, bucket := range result.Buckets {
            bucketInput := &s3.GetBucketTaggingInput{Bucket: bucket.Name}
            bucketOutput, err := p.s3svc.GetBucketTagging(bucketInput)
            if err != nil {
                continue
            }
            if bucketOutput != nil && bucketOutput.TagSet != nil && len(bucketOutput.TagSet) > 0 {
                for _, bucketTag := range bucketOutput.TagSet {
                    if *bucketTag.Key == *tag.Key && *bucketTag.Value == *tag.Value {
                        matchedBuckets = append(matchedBuckets, bucket)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return matchedBuckets, nil
}
```

Thanks
Erkan

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "Resource Groups Tagging API" to achieve this.

I am using AWS SDK for Go v2 in my examples. Unfortunately, I need to provide two versions due to a [bug in the paginators](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/issues/1201) at the moment.

My example returns all S3 buckets that have the tag `Owner=Luke Skywalker`.

Due to the bug, we need to cancel the pagination. I added a comment to the part of the code that wouldn't be needed if the bug is fixed.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/resourcegroupstaggingapi"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/resourcegroupstaggingapi/types"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("unable to create config: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    client := resourcegroupstaggingapi.NewFromConfig(cfg)

    params := resourcegroupstaggingapi.GetResourcesInput{
        ResourceTypeFilters: []string{"s3"},
        TagFilters: []types.TagFilter{
            {
                Key:    aws.String("Owner"),
                Values: []string{"Luke Skywalker"},
            },
        },
    }

    paginator := resourcegroupstaggingapi.NewGetResourcesPaginator(client, &params)

    for paginator.HasMorePages() {
        page, err := paginator.NextPage(context.TODO())
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("unable to read next page: %v\n", err)
            continue
        }

        for _, t := range page.ResourceTagMappingList {
            fmt.Printf("arn: %s\n", *t.ResourceARN)
        }

        // Until the bug (see link below is fixed), we need to do this for the paginator:
        // https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/issues/1201
        if *page.PaginationToken == "" || page.PaginationToken == nil {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me give it a try. I am not using the v2 api yet. I hope I won't habe to change a lot.
Thanks Jens

Comment: @ErkanEssey the same APIs should be available in v1 of the SDK.

Comment: @Erkan Awesome. Glad that it worked for you. Then only one thing left to do: accept my answer, please :)

Comment: @Erkan It has been over two weeks now. Can you please accept the answer.